# How does the Mule caching strategy know when the data has changed?

Tags: caching, mule, anypoint-studio

I'm looking at the cache scope for Mule 3.8.1 in Anypoint Studio 6.1 and wanted to know if/how the caching detects changes to the data?

I see there is a Time to Live and Expiration times which are useful so it is not checking all the time but how can Mule caching be set up to detect changes as if e.g. the data is incorrect in the database and is then fixed I wouldn't want to have to wait an hour or have to redeploy the application to see the change if I can help it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can think you need to invalidate your cache by yourself, if you want the data to be loaded again. Since its your data you know when it is changed and you can trigger the invalidation.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/cache-scope#invalidating-a-cache